# How can I create a MySQL temporary table table and display its data in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a single query to create a new temporary table and get its values in MySQL. The reason behind wanting to do it in one query is I need to pass the query as a variable in a javascript code. When I try adding two queries, the code throws an error.

I tried the following query but it doesn't do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp
SELECT student.id,
student.name,
student.age FROM student;
```

Is there a way I can successfully create a temporary table and display its results in one query?
Thank

Comment: Not in MySQL.  A `select` query returns values to the user.  A `create table as` or `insert` adds rows into a table.  They are separate statements.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you want to do it in one statement?  Why do you need to create a temporary table if you just want to get the query result?

Comment: Try 

    `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS
        SELECT student.id, student.name, student.age 
    FROM student;
    SELECT * FROM temp;`

You will need 2 queries.

Comment: Try this, create temporary table temp as select id, name, age FROM student; select * from temp;

Comment: Definitely sounds like an XY problem.  You *can* write a stored procedure which creates a temporary table and then serves up rows from it.  But first we really need to understand your XY problem ... what are you *really* trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @MikeRobinson thank you for your comment. This query will be passed to a nodeJS code because I want to get the data into a website. I could simply select the data without creating the temporary table but since the problem might involve retrieving data from many different tables and also writing data back to these tables, I thought creating a temporary before displaying the data would make the problem easier.
I will update the question with a query more representative of what I want to do.

Comment: @JosmyFaure That just isn't how this is done. A temporary table isn't going to help you for what you are trying to do. We use `SELECT` to retrieve data and `INSERT` and `UPDATE` to add/modify data. A temporary table doesn't help with any of that directly.